# angular HttpInterceptor cancelled timeout promise aborted request

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My goal is cancel a xhr request if
the lastest has a 401 status.

With the code below I can cancel
the next request but if I try
to do

an other request (ie do login) is aborted
(it need like canceller.reject(reason))

The flow

1 set a parent route (auth) to check if the login is required

2 set a child root which inheriting the auth state

3 when the app hits the route cancel the request to articles and show a modal login

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

function Auth($http) {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: function() {
        return $http.get('/api/auth/isloggedin');
    },
    signin: function(data) {
        return $http.post('/api/auth/signin', data);
    }
  };
}
function loginModal($modal, $rootScope,$templateCache) {
    function successCallback (data) {
        console.log('success',data);
    }
    function errorCallback (data) {
        console.log('fail',data);
    }
    return {
        open : function(){
            var modalInstance =  $modal.open({
                template: $templateCache.get('auth/templates/modal-login.html'),
                controller: 'LoginModalController',
                controllerAs: 'auth'
            });
            return modalInstance.result.then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
        }
    };
}

function HttpInterceptor($rootScope,$q) {
    var canceller = $q.defer();
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            config.timeout = canceller.promise;
            return config;
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                $rootScope.$emit('no-auth', rejection);
                canceller.resolve('Unauthorized');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}

angular.module('auth.services', [])
    .factory('Auth', Auth)
    .factory('HttpInterceptor', HttpInterceptor)
    .factory('loginModal', loginModal);
})();

(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('auth', 
  ['auth.services','auth.controllers','auth.routes'])
    .run(function($rootScope,loginModal,HAS_MODAL_LOGIN){
      $rootScope.$on('no-auth', function(event, data) { 
        if(HAS_MODAL_LOGIN){
          loginModal.open();
        }
      });
});

})();

(function() {
'use strict';

function config($stateProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $stateProvider      
        .state('auth', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            resolve:{
                auth : function(Auth){
                    return Auth.isLoggedIn();
                }
            }

    });
    //Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
}

angular.module('auth.routes', [])
    .config(config);

})();

(function() {
'use strict';

function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider      
        .state('auth.articles', {
            url: '/articles',
            templateUrl: 'articles/templates/index.html',
            controller:'ArticlesController as articles',
            resolve:{
                articlesData : function(Articles){
                    return Articles.get();
                }
            }
    });
}

angular.module('articles.routes', [])
    .config(config);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reject. If you have 401 error, then you may simply open login dialog right there. And if user closed dialog, navigate to home.

Please read this article by Gabe Scholz

http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html

This is exactly what you try to do but much cleaner way.

Comment: thanks I've just seen that tutorial but I want to show a modal login and reject the request (if I find the way :) ) all in all in the real app articles get a 403 status but for the sake of ..... :)

Comment: Then you may try to use $q service right in Auth controller to send out rejects.